# Accessing C# libraries over the web

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

First of all, this question is made because of my lack of knowledge on windows related technologies. Now the question.

I have made an speech recognition application using Windows Speech API, using C#.Net. I am on windows 7 ultimate.

Now I need to make this application into an API, where the other applications can use its services. My other application is a web application.

I am thinking about purchasing a windows instance from Amazon cloud and adding this API into it with a web service, so my other application can access it via a REST api or something.

Is this possible with windows C#, specially with SpeechRecognition?

Comment: The application for Speach is a class library or something else?

Comment: @Max: Right now, it is an application. But I can make it a library (which means, first I have to find how to make libraries in C#)

Comment: You could change it to a library and include it in the solution that needs accessing it. It is possible to call functions from the class library when referenced from you application.

Comment: @Max: Over the web, via rest calls? I will be sending audio files to the api and will be recieving the text

Answer (score 2):

You could try hosting your library inside a wcf service and try making a call to the service from a locally hosted web application.